# Non-empty test results to "Empty test suite" output in ScalaTest with ReactiveMongo plugin

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scalatest, reactivemongo

I'm trying to write a simple test

```
  "CurrencyDao" should "read Currency from the DB" in {
     def collection: JSONCollection = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db.collection[JSONCollection]("currencies")
     collection.find(Json.obj("_id" -> "EUR")).cursor[JsObject].collect[List]().map ( currencies =>
        assertResult(1)(currencies.size)
     )}
```

Running it leads to the **"Empty test suite"** output and, needless to say, an assertion is not checked.

However, the similar test with the insert command executes as expected

```
"CurrencyDao" should "save Currency to the DB" in {
   val json = Json.obj("_id" -> "PLN")

  collection.insert(json).map(lastError =>
    intercept[NoSuchElementException](lastError.err.get)
  )}
```

So, any ideas what's wrong with the first one?

Comment: I think you need to await the result of your future. ScalaTest provides some helpers for this. See [this blog post for example](http://blog.abhinav.ca/blog/2014/09/08/unit-testing-futures-with-scalatest/)

Comment: It turned out that there were some issues with my another method which prepares data for tests, but your answer is also relevant, and awaiting of futures solves the rest of problems which remained after I'd fixed my preparation method.